# Override Generic Method With Concrete Type (type parameter * hides class *)

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, type-parameter

I'd like to override a generic method in a derived class. The catch is I'd like to have a concrete type parameter implementation as so:

```
namespace Stumped
{
    public class Generic<T> where T : new()
    {
        public virtual T Foo()
        {
            return new T();
        }

        public virtual TAnother GenericMethod<TAnother>() where TAnother : new()
        {
            return new TAnother();
        }
    }

    public class Concrete : Generic<Inner1>
    {
        // Concrete return type. Works as expected.
        public override Inner1 Foo()
        {
            return base.Foo();
        }

        // Why doesn't this make sense? Shows 'Type parameter "Inner2" hides class "Inner2"'.
        public override Inner2 GenericMethod<Inner2>()
        {
            return base.GenericMethod<Inner2>();
        }
    }

    public class Inner1 { }

    public class Inner2 { }
}
```

As mentioned, the compiler tells me:

> Type parameter "Inner" hides class "Inner"

I would expect my implementation to work, instead of having to use another generic parameter in this derived class.

Why doesn't this make sense?

Comment: My compiler doesn't show anything.

Comment: Could be a resharper thing. Nonetheless the message is valid. If I were to try to access a property of Inner2 within the overriden GenericMethod, it tells me that there is no definition for that property (because apparently I'm hiding the class).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that at all.

Overriding a method cannot change any part of the method's interface.  Since `GenericMethod<OtherClass>()` is valid for the base class, it must be valid for the derived class too.

This is called the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)
.

As the compiler is warning you, you actually just declared a normal type parameter that happens to have the same name as your class.

Comment: How is this different from the way I override Foo?

Comment: @bitbyte: `Foo` isn't generic.

Comment: Is C++ capable of this? Template function specialization?